# Proving a set is closed and bounded in a specific situation

Tags: general-topology

Good evening,

I’ve read in a research article that:

Given a vector $\gamma\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $l$ a differentiable and continuous function from $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$. If, when $\gamma$ approaches the boundarie of $\Omega$, $l(\gamma)\to -\infty$, then, for a constant $c\in\mathbb{R}$, the set $\{\gamma\in\Omega: l(\gamma) \geq c\}$ is bounded and closed.

I really struggle to understand how we arrive to this implication, if you need more context to help me, let me know, thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @Notebook68, please use MathJax to format mathematical expressions in your question; you can find out how [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: You have hard time proving it because the statement is garbled. In particular, you forgot to assume that $\Omega$ is bounded.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I believe that $\Omega$ can be unbounded so long as we consider the point at infinity to be part of the boundary.

Comment: @blark: Of course, but I doubt OP thinks in these terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A = \{x\in\Omega : l(x)\geq c\}$. If $p$ is a point of the closure of $A$, i.e. exists a sequence $(x_n)$ of elements of $A$ that converges to $p$, then, by the continuity of $l$, we have
$$
\lim l(x_n) = l(\lim x_n) = l(p)
$$
but, because each $x_n\in A$, each $l(x_n)\geq c$. Thus, $l(p) = \lim l(x_n) \geq c$ and $p\in A$. Therefore, $\overline{A}\subset A$, i.e. $A$ is a closed set.

Now, I don't think that $A$ is bounded. Take $\Omega = (0,1)\times\mathbb{R}\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ and $l$ defined by $l(x, y) = -\left(\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{1 - x}\right)$. The boundarie of $\Omega$ is $\{0\}\times\mathbb{R}\cup\{1\}\times\mathbb{R}$ and if $(x,y)\to (0,z)$ or $(x,y)\to (1,z)$, then $l(x,y)\to -\infty$, which satisfy our hipotesis. However, $A$ is not always bounded, since $l(x,y)\geq c$ restricts only the $x$ coordinate leaving $y$ coordinate free to be as big (or small) we want to.

Answer (score 0):

Because $l$ is continuous, the preimage $l^{-1}((-\infty,c))$ will be an open set; since the set in question is the complement of this set, it is closed. Because the limit approaching the boundary of $\Omega$ is $-\infty$, we see that $l^{-1}((-\infty,c))$ is an open neighborhood of the boundary of $\Omega$. We can use this to determine boundedness, but let's first take a small detour to discuss what they mean by the boundary of $\Omega$ and the underlying topology of the space.

In order to define limits as $\gamma$ approaches infinity, we adjoin $\infty$ as a "point at infinity" in $\mathbb{R}^n$. If you look at the standard way to define a limit as $\gamma$ approaches infinity, you can see that this is the same as equipping the regular topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$ with basic open neighborhoods around the point $\infty$ at infinity of the form $\{\gamma\in\mathbb{R}^n|\gamma>M\}$ for some $M\in\mathbb{R}$. With this setup, it is possible for $\infty$ to be a boundary point of $\Omega$ (if and only if $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ is unbounded in $\mathbb{R}^n$).

Returning to the argument, we have already concluded that $l^{-1}((-\infty,c))$ is an open neighborhood of the boundary of $\Omega$. If $\infty$ is not in the boundary of $\Omega$, then $\Omega$ itself is bounded and so $\{\gamma\in\Omega|l(\gamma)\geq c\}\subseteq\Omega$ is bounded. If $\infty$ is in the boundary of $\Omega$, the fact that $l^{-1}((-\infty,c))$ is an open neighborhood of the boundary, and in particular an open neighborhood of $\infty$ (which is in the boundary), we can use the fact that it must contain a basic open neighborhood of $\infty$ of the form described in the last paragraph. Thus, the complement $l^{-1}((-\infty,c))^c=\{\gamma\in\mathbb{R}^n|l(\gamma)\geq c\}$ is contained in the complement of this basic open set, which bounds it.

Notice that it is necessary to consider $\infty$ as a potential boundary point to get this result to work: if $\Omega=\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ in the space $\mathbb{R}$, the function $l(x)=\frac{-1}{|x|}$ is differentiable on $\Omega$. If we don't consider $\infty$ as a boundary point, then the boundary of $\Omega$ is $\{0\}$ and $\lim_{x\to0}l(x)=-\infty$. However, for any $c<0$, $\{x\in\mathbb{R}|l(x)\geq c\}$ is unbounded. This situation is ruled out by allowing $\infty$ as a boundary point, establishing that $l$ does not approach $-\infty$ on its boundary, since $lim_{x\to\infty}=0$.